# Scale vertices by precise percentage in Edit Mode?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

When I'm in Edit Mode and have some vertices selected in my mesh, I can hit <kbd>s</kbd> and move the mouse to scale the selected vertices, and I can see the amount I'm scaling in the info bar. But how do numerically enter a precise amount to scale? For example, 92%?

Comment: S and enter 1.92 should do it precisely.

Comment: @Denis  is correct you can scale with the letter **S** and typing a number, just keep in mind that if your object has been scaled in object mode without applying scale, you might run into unexpected results .

Comment: @cegaton you are right, the operations are applied to local coordinates of the object.

Comment: @Denis Ah, you just start typing the value. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To scale the mesh in edit mode all you need to do is to hit <kbd>S</kbd> hotkey and enter 0.92 i.e. 92% and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply.

As all operations are applied to objects' coordinates, make sure to apply the object scale in object mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select Scale from the menu to make is possible to scale the mesh proportionally in edit mode.